# Making up datasets with matching or distinct summary statistics

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, descriptive-statistics, median

4)  Make up three data sets with 6 numbers each that have:
a)  The same mean but different standard deviations.
b)  The same mean but different medians.
c)  The same median but different means.

Can anyone tell me the procedure of finding the data sets which match the above mentioned criteria.

Comment: Is this [tag:self-study]? Please read its description in the link and add the tag if it fits. Also read the recommendations if that's the case. Otherwise ignore.

Comment: Also, your question is currently too simply worded, I'd recommend you to add more details to bring some attention to the actual issues you're facing with the question.

Comment: @Firebug thanks for the reply, let me change it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a), an example could be
$$D_1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6)$$ $$D_2= (0,1,2,5,6,7)$$ $$D_3=(-1,0,1,3,6,12)$$
the mean is 3.5 for all three but the standard deviations differ. Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: How did you find them, I mean is there a formula or some procedure?

Comment: Just made them up! You could go by trail and error, or you could just set a mean e.g. 3.5 and set it equal to a sum of 5 numbers of your choice divided by 6 and then solve for the 6th number in the sum. In $D_1$ for example, you would have 
$3.5 = \frac{1+2+3+4+5+x}{6}$. Solving for $x$ completes the dataset. Repeat two times, being careful that the numbers are 1) differently heterogeneous (different sd) 2) contain 3.5, the mean.